# textbox only allow numeric and comma

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I have a textbox and I need to let user enter only amount of money, which means only numbers and a comma

here is what I have

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_tutar" runat="server" onkeypress="this.value=this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')"></asp:TextBox>
```

this code above only allows numeric, it deletes the comma. how can I update to let user enter float number in textbox ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this regular expression:

```
/[^\d,]/g
```

As in:

```
this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d,]/g,'')
```

Of course this doesn't really mean the string will be a valid numeric value; e.g. `2,,0,1` would be considered fine. You really should be doing full server-side validation using [`decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) or something similar

Comment: can I do it on client side?

Comment: You probably could, but in general, you should use server-side validation for any user input. There no guarantee your clients will use javascript or respect the validation on the client. And of course, malicious users can always post anything they want via raw HTTP requests, rendering client-side validation meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can also use required field validator to do ths,

Better way go with javascript at client side for performance, use below script

```
function isValidNo(str) {
            var inbadChars = "\t\n\r^&*=~`';<>?[]{}abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            //debugger;
            for (n = 0; n < str.length; n++) //filter for invalid chars
            {
                if (inbadChars.indexOf(str.charAt(n)) != -1) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Recomended to use server side tryparse as well, as on somebrowser sometimes scripets may not work.